# Support External Source in YouTube Player

Tags: video, youtube

May I ask if YouTube Player support other video sources? such as Alibaba and AEM DAM?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it does not.

However there are plenty of open source and 3rd party video players that will play videos streamed in the most common formats - e.g. HLS, MPEG DASH, streamed mp4 files etc.

Examples:

- https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js. (Browser)
- https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html (cross platform client)
- https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer (Android)